# How to prevent vertical scroll bars appearing on C3 charts

Tags: svg, c3.js, gridstack

I have a grid(Gridstack.js) containing C3 charts. The chart renders with an unexpected vertical scroll bar as shown in fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/plax/avxdekyL/13/

```
var options = {
    cell_height: 80,
    resizable: {autoHide: false, handles: 'se'},
    'auto':true,
    vertical_margin: 10
};
$('.grid-stack').gridstack(options);

var x = document.getElementsByClassName("grid-stack-item-content");

var i;
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
   console.log(i);
   loadChart($(x[i]));
}
```

The scrollbar appears only when there is a svg element like a chart but works fine for simple text on grid.

Is there any other fix, than setting 'overflow' to hidden as mentioned in a prior thread.

Anybody know why the svg is causing this scroll bar to appear?